# Angular directive not working, directive not changing element display

Tags: angular, directive

I have checked documentation and help online, but nothing works. As I can't use console.log from a directive (excuse my novelty) I don't know how to test it or check if it is properly working.

My intention is to show/hide elements depending on the user's Role. I pass what roles are allowed for each element. Then it checks in the directive if the current user's role matches any of the passed roles.

```
<div IfRole="office,shop">hi</div> //In the directive, it should transform this string into an array of roles
```

```
import { AfterContentInit, Directive, ElementRef, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthService } from "../services/auth.service";
import { OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from "@angular/core";
import { UserI } from "../models/user";
import { IfStmt } from "@angular/compiler";
import { type } from "os";

@Directive({
  selector: "[IfRole]"
})
export class ElementsRoleDirective {
   UserRoles: string[];
  User: UserI;

  @Input() set IfRole(roles:  string) {
     this.UserRoles = roles.split(",");
  }

  public constructor(
    private el: ElementRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private AuthService: AuthService,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {

    this.AuthService.currentUser.subscribe(data => {
      this.User = data;
    });
    if (!this.UserRoles.includes(this.User.role))
    this.viewContainer.clear();
    else {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 this.AuthService.currentUser.subscribe(data => {
      this.User = data;

      if (!this.UserRoles.includes(this.User.role))
        this.viewContainer.clear();
      else {
       this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
      }
 });
```

i've placed async code inside of a callback, and now it sholud be handled in the right moment

Comment: Same thing, "hi" always appear. No matter what I pass.